# onClick function of an input type="button" not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code which on clicking the button "Get more fields" will create a copy of the entire div and create fields. But on clicking the button nothing is happening. All the other buttons are working fine. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="readroot" style="display: none">

    <input type="button" value="Remove review"
        onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />

    <input name="cd" value="title" />

    <select name="rankingsel">
        <option>Rating</option>
        <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
        <option value="good">Good</option>
        <option value="ok">OK</option>
        <option value="poor">Poor</option>
        <option value="bad">Bad</option>
    </select><br /><br />

    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="review">Short review</textarea>
    <br />Radio buttons included to test them in Explorer:<br />
    <input type="radio" name="something" value="test1" />Test 1<br />
    <input type="radio" name="something" value="test2" />Test 2

</div>

<form method="post" action="index1.php">

    <span id="writeroot"></span>

    <input type="button" id="moreFields" value="Give me more fields!"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Send form" />

</form>
</body>
</html>

<script>

var counter = 0;


function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName)
            newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}

window.onload = moreFields;
</script>
```

Comment: open this in chrome, right click anywhere on the page -> inspect element and check the bottom right of the opened panel for a red `x` and click on it. are there any errors? if so, share those errors here

Comment: Checked earlier for errors.No errors are showing

Comment: put your script tags inside of the body tag

Comment: there's no onclick method defined in that button either like Sajith is saying in his answer

Comment: I tried the onclick() function earlier also but it still wasn't working.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to change the ID of the button to be different from the function name
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFwK3/)

```js
var counter = 0;


function moreFields() {
  counter++;
  var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
  newFields.id = '';
  newFields.style.display = 'block';
  var newField = newFields.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
    var theName = newField[i].name
    if (theName) newField[i].name = theName + counter;
  }
  var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
  insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields, insertHere);
}

window.onload = moreFields();
```

```html
<div id="readroot" style="display: none">
  <input type="button" value="Remove review" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input name="cd" value="title" />
  <select name="rankingsel">
    <option>Rating</option>
    <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
    <option value="good">Good</option>
    <option value="ok">OK</option>
    <option value="poor">Poor</option>
    <option value="bad">Bad</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br />
  <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="review">Short review</textarea>
  <br />Radio buttons included to test them in Explorer:
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="something" value="test1" />Test 1
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="something" value="test2" />Test 2</div>
<form method="post" action="index1.php"> <span id="writeroot"></span>

  <input type="button" onclick="moreFields();" id="moreFieldsButton" value="Give me more fields!" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send form" />
</form>
```

Comment: MaveRick i removed the id=moreFields and it worked..Thanks alot

Comment: Can you tell me why it wasn't working earlier? Was something clashing?

Comment: because you where calling the object "moreFields" which is an HTML element, rather than calling the function "moreFields", each element in your document will be a JS object named as of it's ID, So you can't name a function just like an element ID

Comment: Can also block on the name. I just got this bug in Chrome and Opera, but not in Firefox, maybe because the form was dynamically generated. The jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/44wuu776/ has the same behavior with the 3 browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You've forgot to define an onclick attribute to do something when the button is clicked, so nothing happening is the correct execution, see below;

```
<input type="button" id="moreFields" onclick="moreFields()" value="Give me more fields!"  />
                                     ----------------------
```

Comment: Tried the onclick() function also but still not working

Comment: did you put the script tag inside of the body tag?

Comment: Yes I put the script tag  inside the body tag but it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

you could also try creating a button, this will work if you put it outside of the form;

```
<button onClick="moreFields(); return false;">Give me more fields!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try:

```
<input type="button" id="moreFields" onclick="alert('The text will be show!!'); return false;" value="Give me more fields!"  />
```

It's worked well. So I think the problem is position of moreFields() function. Ensure that function will be define before your input tag.

Pls try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function moreFields() {
        alert("The text will be show");
    }
</script>

<input type="button" id="moreFields" onclick="moreFields()" value="Give me more fields!"  />
```

Hope it helped.